# Stripe iFrame being blocked - rails and stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am making a checkout form with stripe and rails. I have a `shop_controller` that serves a list of products in the `shop#index`. Then that leads to the `shop#show` where the stripe form is located, and users can purchase a product.

Right now when clicking the button to make a purchase (using the fake card stripe gives you), all that happens is the button endlessly spins, and I get the following errors in the console:

`GET https://checkout.stripe.com/api/account/lookup?email=MYEMAILADDRESS&key=&locale=en-US 400 (Bad Request)`

and

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://checkout.stripe.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

When I am adding my email to the form, I am also getting this error:

`The specified value "MYEMAILADDRESS" is not a valid email address.`

Here is my set up

**routes.rb**

```
resources :shop
```

**shop_controller**

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @products = Product.all
      end

      def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
      end

      # the create happens in the show action
      def create
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          :email => params[:stripeEmail],
          :source  => params[:stripeToken]
        )

        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :customer    => customer.id,
          :amount      => @product.price * 100,
          :description => @product.description,
          :currency    => 'usd'
        )

        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
          flash[:error] = e.message
          redirect_to new_charge_path
      end

    end
```

**show.html.erb (where the form is rendered to pay)**

```
<div class='shop-show'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
        <h2><%= @product.name %></h2>
        <hr class="generic">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="white_panel">
          <%= form_for @product, url: url_for(controller: 'shop', action: 'create' ) do %>
            <% if flash[:error].present? %>
              <div id="error_explanation">
                <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <script src="http://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                data-description="<%= @product.description %>"
                data-amount="<%= @product.price * 100 %>"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-shipping-address=true>
            </script>
          <% end %>
          <img class="img-responsive" width='400' height='250' src="<%= @product.pictures.first.image.url %>">
          <h2><%= @product.description %></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone set up this kind of functionality before? This was closely followed using the link provided by stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails. Any help with this set up would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Checkout ctript tag's URL there needs to be retrieved over HTTPS.  Try swapping this:

```
<script src="http://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
```

for this:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
```

Comment: I had it at https to start, and it wasn't working, so I changed it to http. Somehow (maybe another config? stale browser? etc) I changed it back, and it worked. Thanks!